# Angular - problem at removing files with Node JS REST API

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, api, rest

I'm working on a project based on Angular.

I have a list of pictures from a REST API built with Node JS.  My goal is to add a functionality that allows a user to remove a picture.  I tried to implement it with Node JS too.
Here is the code below.

**Node JS Controller :**

```
 const remove = (req) => {
    
      const fileName2 = req.params.photo;
      const directoryPath = "/path/to/uploads/";
    
      fs.unlinkSync(directoryPath+fileName2); // tested with asynchronous method fs.unlink too, same result observed
    
    };
```

**Node JS Route part:**

```
router.get("/remove/:photo", controller.remove);
```

**Angular web page :** (linked to a ts controller to return an array of pictures)

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> <a href="http://IPSERVER:PORT/remove/{{item.name}}">Delete link</a> </h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is partially working because I can see in the backend that the picture located in my server is removed.  But in the frontend there is a strange behaviour since the Angular web page don't stop loading and I finally get that error message :

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink
> '/path/to/upload/picture_M42_20210519_0q3x44b.jpg'

I want the picture to be removed in the web page too and I'd like to understand why the page can't stop loading. How could I do ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never send a response in your node-request handler, change it to something like:

```
const remove = (req, res) => {
    
    const fileName2 = req.params.photo;
    const directoryPath = "/path/to/uploads/";
    
    fs.unlinkSync(directoryPath+fileName2);
    res.send("File was removed");
    
};
```

Comment: My bad, all my apologizes for that oversight.. Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: The @eol proposition works very well. But it asks me an other question : the ```res.send()```  opens a page after the removal with a custom message. How could it be possible to prevent that page to be openned and replace it by a success alert message on the web page ?

Comment: `res.send()` does not "open" a page - it happens on the client side because you're using a link (`<a href=":..">`) to perform the request. You could simply use a `button` instead of a link and send the request through angular in your `(click)` handler.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I managed to do that with a ```button (click)="remove($event, item.name)"></button>``` in the html and ```remove (event:any, item:any){this.http.get("http://IP:PORT/remove/" + item).subscribe(data => {}); }``` in the ts. That works, there is no "redirection" and the file on the back side is well removed. But it's still present on the client side. When I refresh the page, it disappears. How could I do it to make a kind of automatically refresh after each deletion ?

Comment: You'd simply have to remove the element/item from `myArray` inside of `.subscribe`.

Comment: Ok I tried ```const id = this.myArray.indexOf(item);```  then ```this.myArray.splice(id,  1);``` but it removes the bad item on the client side whereas the selected item is well removed on the back side. What's more when I do a ```console.log(id)``` it returns "-1"..

Comment: Since you're passing `item.name` to the function, you probably need to do: `const id = this.myArray.findIndex(element => element.name === item);` Also just to be sure add a check for `-1` which basically means that the index was not found.

Comment: Great it works perfectly now, thank you mery much @eol for your help ! :)